# Different websocket endpoints with Apache2 vs "manage.py runserver". Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, apache2, django-channels, channel

I have different endpoints when i run Django in apache compare to when I run it in the terminal.

Can it be some configuration in apache?

I belive it can be this ?
**Apache 2 conf**
`ProxyPass "/ws/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8000/"`

What does this mean; "/ws/"?

**Apache to work:**
`ws_urlpatterns = [path('some_url/', Andring.as_asgi()), ]`

**Run in terminal:**
 `ws_urlpatterns = [path('ws/some_url/', Andring.as_asgi()), ]`

**In JS:**
`const socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws/some_url/");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

The examples below are only a very basic idea to help you get started. Please read the documentation on the individual directives.

In addition, if you wish to have caching enabled, consult the documentation from mod_cache.

```
ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
# Forward Proxy
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
  Require host internal.example.com
</Proxy>
# Websocket Upgrade (2.4.47 and later)
ProxyPass "/some/ws/capable/path/" "http://example.com/some/ws/capable/path/" upgrade=websocket
```